# Red Hat Development Suite missing rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms

Tags: rhel7, redhat-containers

What's the trick to enabling rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms?

I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Suite subscription and have been trying to install Red Hat Development Suite in RHEL7. Following the steps outlined in the [installation guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_development_suite/2.1/html/installation_guide/installing_red_hat_development_suite#red_hat_enterprise_linux_prerequisites):

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms
```

Results in this error:

```
Error: 'rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.
```

If I list the valid repositories, rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms is missing!

I'm expecting that it should exist as part of my subscription.  Has anybody had this issue? What am I missing?

```
subscription-manager list --consumed


Red Hat Software Collections (for RHEL Server)
MRG Realtime
Red Hat Software Collections Beta (for RHEL Server)
Oracle Java (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Developer Toolset (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Oracle Java (for RHEL Server) - Extended Update Support
Red Hat Enterprise Linux High Availability (for RHEL Server) - Extended Update Support
Red Hat Enterprise Linux High Availability (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Load Balancer (for RHEL Server) - Extended Update Support
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Load Balancer (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Real Time
Red Hat Enterprise Linux High Performance Networking (for RHEL Server) - Extended Update Support
Red Hat Enterprise Linux High Performance Networking (for RHEL Compute Node)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux High Performance Networking (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat EUCJP Support (for RHEL Server) - Extended Update Support
Red Hat Beta
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Scalable File System (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Scalable File System (for RHEL Server) - Extended Update Support
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server - Extended Update Support
dotNET on RHEL Beta (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat S-JIS Support (for RHEL Server) - Extended Update Support
dotNET on RHEL (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Resilient Storage (for RHEL Server) - Extended Update Support
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Resilient Storage (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Container Images Beta
Red Hat Container Development Kit
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host Beta
Red Hat Container Images
```

Comment: That repo should be available with your subscription -- I just checked, and I can see it. Try to run `subscription-manager refresh`. If it doesn't help, try to re-register (see the [doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_subscription_management/1/html/rhsm/registering-cmd)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob but I've tried that a million times already with no success.  I ended up re-subscribing and with a new account ... that worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked in the end, though it's weird that a new account was required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. To resolve it, I:

1. Validated I was registered for the *Red Hat Developer Subscription* on the [Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/management/subscriptions).
2. On my RHEL 7.5 Server, I opened the *Red Hat Subscription Manager* interface from the main menu: Applications ->  System Tools -> Subscription Manager
3. Verify that *Red Hat Developer Subscription* is not listed on the *My Subscriptions* Tab
4. On the *All Available Subscriptions* tab, click the *Update* button.
   a. The *Red Hat Developer Subscription* should now be listed.
   b. Select the subscription and click the *Attach* button
5. The *Red Hat Developer Subscription* should now be listed on the *My Subscriptions* Tab

Upon completion, I was able to enable the devtools-rpms repo.

```
#> subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms

Repository 'rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms' is enabled for this system.
```