# can't enable rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms to install llvm-toolset-7

Tags: redhat, rhel7

trying to install llvm-toolset-7 on rhel 7 machine
instructions say to first enable rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms. however, it is not available to me.

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms

Error: 'rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation? It probably needs to be fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313604/red-hat-development-suite-missing-rhel-7-server-devtools-rpms